# How to show the records from database where date = today in Asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to count the rows where the date stored in my DB = today's date. Please help me...

```
Dim con2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SUJAY GHOSH\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\DateTest\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        con2.Open()
        Dim com2 As New SqlCommand("select count(*) from APPOINT WHERE A_DATE='" & Today & "'", con2)
        row_count2 = com2.ExecuteScalar()
        Label2.Text = row_count2
```

Comment: Parameterise your command text query to start with rather than sting concatenation, then ensure your using a date data type both in the DB and your parameter

Comment: SQL Server has *multiple* functions to get the current date and time: `GETDATE()`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `SYSDATETIME()`, `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`, `SYSUTCDATETIME()` to name a few (that list is *not* exhaustive). More than likely you don't even need to parametrise.

Comment: It also depends exactly what you have stored in the database. If you have stored just the date then you can compare to today's date for equality. If you have both date and time stored in the database then you will need to either get just the date portion and compare for equality or else compare to a range of greater than or equal to today's date and less than tomorrow's date.

Comment: If these dates have a time component then you need a date range `>= CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AND < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))`. You also have multiple side issues just in those few lines of code: You need `Using` on your connection and command objects. Do not use `AttachDbFilename` or `User Instance` which are deprecated and have issues, instead create the database normally through SSMS, and connect directly to that database. You need to parameterize your query, do not inject data into it using concatenation.

Comment: Could someone please write the code for me? As I am new to asp.net I can't understand clearly. It will very helpful if someone wrote me the code.

Comment: Why are you using Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work:

```vb
Dim com2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM APPOINT WHERE (A_DATE2 = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))", con2)
Dim row_count2 As String = com2.ExecuteScalar()
```